# JavaFX 2.2 (8) Clickable groups in a grid becomes unclickable

Tags: java, 3d, javafx-8

A `javafx.scene.layout.GridPane` contains two pawns inherited from `javafx.scene.Group`. Pawns contains a `javafx.scene.shape.Cylinder`.

After two clicks on any Pawn, the mouse click event handler is no longer called. It seems `Group` is clickable when it has only one 3D children, why?

The code of `Pawn` class (minimized):

```
class Pawn extends Group {

   private static final double DEPTH  = 14.0;
   /*   */ static final double RADIUS = 30.0;
   /*   */ static final double MARGIN = 10.0;

   private final Cylinder shape;

   Pawn() {
      shape = new Cylinder( RADIUS, DEPTH );
      shape.setRotationAxis( Rotate.X_AXIS );
      shape.setRotate( 90.0 );
      shape.setTranslateZ( -DEPTH - 4.0 );
      getChildren().setAll( shape );
      setTranslateX( MARGIN );
   }

   void setQueen() {
      shape.setHeight( 2.0 * DEPTH );
      final Sphere crown = new Sphere( RADIUS / 4.0 );
      crown.setTranslateX( shape.getTranslateX());
      crown.setTranslateY( shape.getTranslateY());
      crown.setTranslateZ( -2.2 * DEPTH );
      crown.setMaterial( new PhongMaterial( Color.CYAN ));
      getChildren().add( crown );
   }
}
```

The code of the application (minimized):

```
public final class NotClickable extends Application {

   private int clickCount;

   private void onPawnClicked( Pawn pawn ) {
      System.err.println( "onPawnClicked" );
      if( ++clickCount > 1 ) {
         pawn.setQueen(); // pawns becomes no longer clickable
      }
   }

   private Pawn addCell( GridPane pane, int row, int col ) {
      final double size  = 2.0 * ( Pawn.MARGIN + Pawn.RADIUS );
      final double depth = 14.0;
      final Box    cell  = new Box( size, size, depth );
      final Pawn   pawn  = new Pawn();
      pane.add( cell, col, row );
      pane.add( pawn, col, row );
      pawn.setOnMouseClicked( e -> onPawnClicked( pawn ));
      return pawn;
   }

   @Override
   public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
      final GridPane          pane   = new GridPane();
      final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera( true );
      camera.setNearClip  ( 0.1 );
      camera.setFarClip   ( 4000.0 );
      camera.setTranslateZ( -1000 );
      camera.setTranslateX( 100 );
      camera.setTranslateY( 1500 );
      camera.setRotationAxis( Rotate.X_AXIS );
      camera.setRotate( 45 );
      final Scene scene = new Scene( pane, 600, 1000, true );
      scene.setCamera( camera );
      scene.setFill  ( Color.LIGHTBLUE );
      stage.setScene ( scene );
      addCell( pane, 0, 0 );
      addCell( pane, 0, 1 );
      stage.show();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }
}
```

The visible states of application:

- Before second click: [image: Before second click]
- After second click:
  [image: After second click]

The output:

```
onPawnClicked
onPawnClicked
```

Clicking on any pawn after second click is without any effect, even on non transformed pawn.

**Question: How to maintain the mouse click event handler?**

**EDIT** [I've filled a bug into JavaFX-JIRA database](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38336)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Martin Sladecek updated RT-38336:

```
    Status: Resolved  (was: New)
Resolution: Not an Issue
```

This is because of the default `pickOnBounds` settings.
`GridPane` (as any region) has it set to true, but `Group (Pawn)` does not.
So once you add the sphere, you get to the state where the `GridPane` wins because it's picked by bounds (which include the sphere) and is closer than the cylinder inside the pawn. The pawn itself is not picked by bounds, so it's distance is the distance to the cylinder.

**Anyway, when doing 3D in JavaFX, `pickOnBounds` is your friend (or enemy?)**. You usually want everything to be `pickOnBounds == false`, otherwise any object basically occupies the whole cube (bounds) that surrounds it. This is usually false by default, except for all the `Regions`/`Panes`/`Controls`.

In your case, setting the `pane.setPickOnBounds( false );` will fix the issue.